# "Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference." when using large-size array and MPI_BARRIER

Tags: fortran, mpi, slurm, mpich

I used Fortran with MPI (CRAY's compiler) for my code.  I used 512 cores, and I found that as my variable exceeds certain size, the code crashed at MPI_BARRIER, and the error message is

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
.
.
.
```

One possibly useful information is that I print out a tag (i.e., write(*,*) "tag") before conducting MPI_BARRIER, and I found that the number of outputted tags (426) plus the number of the repeated error messages (86) is equal to the cores I used (512).

I think this is memory issue.  I use slurm to submit my job, and I remember I've tried something like "ulimit -s unlimited" (couldn't find the web now...), but I haven't been able to solve this problem.

Comment: Run in a debugger. If you have a Cray you probably have some debugger that came with that environment. Alternatively wrap your code in a script that pops up an xterm with gdb only for rank 0. Also: `MPI_Barrier` is almost never needed. Unless you're doing it to synchronize a timer I'm willing to bet that your code doesn't need it.

Comment: Please see [ask] and especilly [mcve]. Some reproducing code is necessary here. Try also error checking features that your compiler offers.

Comment: I agree that Barriers are normally not needed. I use them only during the initialization phase to synchronize output messages announcing the progress of the program initialization.

Comment: A third for barriers being almost always not needed - but you might just be saying the barrier is only there for debugging, it's not 100% clear. But this may well be a bug elsewhere. You have compiled and run with all the run time checks turned on? That's -R and some extra options with the Cray compiler if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes - checking the man page recompile with -Rbcdps . You will also want -g or one of the -G options. See the man page. Also see if you can reproduce the bug on a smaller number of processes and/or with a smaller problem size - you will make your life much easier.